# Matrix is singular error in GraphSLAM

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, slam, singularity

I have gone through [The GraphSLAM Algorithm with Applications to Large-Scale Mapping of Urban Structures](http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/thrun.graphslam.pdf). I implemented the code for GraphSLAM. The fundamental formula of GraphSLAM is

$$\mu = \Omega^{-1}\xi$$

When I inverse $\Omega$ it gives me an error that `Matrix is singular`.

In the above document there are some hints how to avoid this error. But I failed to understand that. On the eighth page of the above document - on page 410 - they discuss it in section ***4. The GraphSLAM Algorithm*** portion. If anybody can understand it, please help me to understand.

From the text:

> In particular, line 2 in GraphSLAM_linearize initializes
>   the information elements. The “infinite” information entry in
>   line 3 fixes the initial pose $x_0$ to (0 0 0)$^T$ . It is necessary, since
>   otherwise the resulting matrix becomes singular, reflecting the
>   fact that from relative information alone we cannot recover
>   absolute estimates.

I added my code here for better understanding

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.ujmp.core.SparseMatrix;
import org.ujmp.core.Matrix;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Matrix omega = SparseMatrix.Factory.zeros(5, 5);
    Matrix Xi=SparseMatrix.Factory.zeros(5,1);
    int i = 0, i1 = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 0,l=0,l1=0;
    double[] timex = new double[5];
    double[] forwardx = new double[5];
    double[] angularx = new double[5];
    double[]x1=new double[5];
    double[]y1=new double[5];
    double[]theta1=new double[5];
    double []landx=new double[2];
    double[]landy=new double[2];
    double[] timeya = new double[2];
    double[] codea = new double[2];
    double[] rangea = new double[2];
    double[] bearinga = new double[2];
    Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/a.txt"));
    Scanner y = new Scanner(new File("/home/froboticscse/IdeaProjects/UJMPtest/src/main/java/b.txt"));
    while (x.hasNext()) {

        double time = x.nextDouble();
        double forward = x.nextDouble();
        double angular = x.nextDouble();
        timex[i] = time;
        forwardx[i] = forward;
        angularx[i] = angular;
        x1[i]=((forwardx[i]*0.006+Math.cos(0+(angularx[i]*0.006)/2)));
        y1[i]=((forwardx[i]*0.006+Math.sin(0+(angularx[i]*0.006)/2)));
        theta1[i]=(angularx[i]*0.006);
        i++;
    }

    while (y.hasNext()) {
        double timey = y.nextDouble();
        double code = y.nextDouble();
        double range = y.nextDouble();
        double bearing = y.nextDouble();
        timeya[i1] = timey;
        codea[i1] = code;
        rangea[i1] = range;
        bearinga[i1] = bearing;

        i1++;

    }
    while (k1 < timex.length && k2 < timeya.length) {
        if (timex[k1] < timeya[k2]) {
            omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1);
            omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k1 + 1);
            Xi.setAsDouble(x1[l],k1,0);
            k1++;
            l++;
        } else if (timex[k1] == timeya[k2]) {
            landx[l1]=x1[k1]+rangea[k2]*(Math.cos(bearinga[k2]+theta1[k1]));
            omega.setAsDouble(1, k1, k2);
            omega.setAsDouble(1, k2, k1);
            Xi.setAsDouble((landx[l1]+x1[l1]),k1,0);
            k2++;
            l1++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing to add");
        }
       // System.out.println(Xi);
    }
    System.out.println(omega);
   /* Matrix mu=omega.inv().mtimes(Xi);
    System.out.println(mu);*/
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide either more details or source code for your implementation? Also, you should note that when a matrix is *singular* it is **not** invertible. So, you are likely getting this error when you try to compute $\Omega^{-1}$.

Comment: I add the code for better understanding

Comment: @koverman47 https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/how-to-avoid-matrix-singularity-in-graph-slam?noredirect=1#comment26043_16094    Check this link. As I don't get my answer I repeat my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to singularity in matrix (i.e. the condition of matrix during which determinant of matrix becomes zero), matrix cannot be inverted.

So you can possibly try pseudo-inverse. It gives most approximated form of inverse matrix. For more information visit this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

Answer (score 0):

Just as [manna kalsariya](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/16065/20709) suggested, you can try to use the pseudo inverse. The README of the [Universal Java Matrix Package](https://github.com/ujmp/universal-java-matrix-package) (see "Quick Start") shows that the pseudo inverse is implemented and available for you to use. Instead of `Matrix mu=omega.inv().mtimes(Xi);`, try `Matrix mu=omega.pinv().mtimes(xi);`.

Comment: pinv() working. But the author suggest something in his algorithm which is not related to pseudo inverse. I don't understand what he mean in the above picture. Can any one explain what author suggest? Also the answer I get after `pinv()` don't think this is right answer.

Comment: @EllenaMori the pseudo-inverse won't be an exact inverse (because one doesn't exist) so it may not appear as you expected.