# How to avoid matrix singularity in GraphSLAM

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, ekf, singularity

I am trying to implement GraphSLAM from Sebastian Thrun's paper, [The GraphSLAM Algorithm with Applications to Large-Scale Mapping of Urban Structures](http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/thrun.graphslam.pdf).

When I compute the inverse of my information matrix, $\Omega^{-1}$, I get an error, `Matrix is Singular`, because $\Omega$ is [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix). How could I avoid matrix singularity when implementing GraphSLAM?

Please don't suggest me `pinv()` method it cannot give me actual answer.

I had considered using a pseudo-inverse, but, instead, I want to prevent $\Omega$ from becoming singular so that I can compute the exact inverse.

Below is where $\Omega$ is computed (see line 7), from **Table 2. Calculation of  and ξ in GraphSLAM**:

[image: Table 2. Calculation of and ξ in GraphSLAM]

Comment: It is a 3*3 matrix where diagonal elements are 0.001 and all other elements are zero.

Comment: I retracted my earlier comments. I saw $R_t^{-1}$ and assumed that that was the inverse matrix you were computing. You should update your post to include more details on the $\Omega^{-1}$ computation, because it is not performed in the given pseudo code.

Comment: I have only this pseudo code. This is the problem of this implementation. So that I am looking for help.

Comment: Is the [code here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/16062/20709) the code that you are using?

Comment: Yes This is the code that I am using.

Comment: If you don't want to use a pseudo-inverse, you can regularize $\Omega$ by adding $\Omega := \Omega + \epsilon I$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$. Also, looking at your first comment, if $\Omega$ is a diagonal with 0.001, then it should be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Omega$ is singular, you cannot avoid a matrix singularity.   This is like saying you want to solve the system of equations $$x = 1$$ $$x = 7$$

There are many techniques to avoid robotic singularities, but if the math represents a pose whereby a degree of freedom is lost in the mechanism, there is no way to get around a singular (and therefore non-invertible) matrix.